# SQL query returns blank output when running inside Python script

Tags: python, sql, json, python-3.x

I have a python script that is supposed to loop through a text file and gather the domain as an argument from each line in the text file. Then it is supposed to use the domain as an argument in a SQL query. The issue is when I'm passing in the **domain_name** as an argument the JSON output the script produces is blank. If I set the domain_name argument in my sql query directly inside the query then the script outputs perfect JSON format. As you can see in the top of my script right below def connect_to_db() I start to loop through the text file. I'm not sure where in my code the error is occurring by any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

**Code**

```
from __future__ import print_function

try:
    import psycopg2
except ImportError:
    raise ImportError('\n\033[33mpsycopg2 library missing. pip install psycopg2\033[1;m\n')
    sys.exit(1)

import re
import sys
import json
import pprint

DB_HOST = 'crt.sh'
DB_NAME = 'certwatch'
DB_USER = 'guest'


def connect_to_db():
    filepath = 'test.txt'
    with open(filepath) as fp:
        for cnt, domain_name in enumerate(fp):
            print("Line {}: {}".format(cnt, domain_name))
            print(domain_name)
            domain_name = domain_name.rstrip()

            conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname={0} user={1} host={2}".format(DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_HOST))
            cursor = conn.cursor()
            cursor.execute(
                "SELECT c.id, x509_commonName(c.certificate), x509_issuerName(c.certificate) FROM certificate c, certificate_identity ci WHERE c.id = ci.certificate_id AND ci.name_type = 'dNSName' AND lower(ci.name_value) = lower('%s') AND x509_notAfter(c.certificate) > statement_timestamp();".format(
                    domain_name))

            unique_domains = cursor.fetchall()

        # print out the records using pretty print
        # note that the NAMES of the columns are not shown, instead just indexes.
        # for most people this isn't very useful so we'll show you how to return
        # columns as a dictionary (hash) in the next example.
            pprint.pprint(unique_domains)

            outfilepath = domain_name + ".json"
            with open(outfilepath, 'a') as outfile:
                    outfile.write(json.dumps(unique_domains, sort_keys=True, indent=4))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    connect_to_db()
```

Comment: You're using `.format` on the sql string, but there are no `{}` anywhere in it...

Comment: It's also poor form to use `format()` because that's open to sql injection. You're either confusing two methods of string interpolation (which you shouldn't be using) or using the `%s` placeholder incorrectly for a parameterized query.

Comment: @SuperStew Thanks for your reply! Where should I put the {}?

Comment: @roganjosh Thanks for your response! What should I use instead of format()?

Comment: @bedford wherever you want the `domain_name` to go

Comment: I'm on my phone and copy is not playing ball. Get rid of `format()` and use `c.execute('the_query_string', (domain_name,))`. You may have to swap `%s` for `?`. `the_query_string` is your original query, I just can't seem to copy paste it.

Comment: @SuperStew That seemed to work. Do you have any idea of how to add this "x509_*(c.certificate)" to the SELECT clause. I tried adding it to the end of the SELECT statement after adding a comma but I got this error message: 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "5:33pm", line 43, in <module>
    connect_to_db()
  File "5:33pm", line 32, in connect_to_db
    lower(%s) AND x509_notAfter(c.certificate) > statement_timestamp()''',(domain_name,))
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: column "x509_" does not exist
LINE 2: x509_issuerName(c.certificate), x509_*(c.certificate) FROM c...

Answer (score 2):

Don't use format to create your SQL statement. Use ? placeholders and then a tuple of the values to insert:

```
c.execute('''SELECT c.id, x509_commonName(c.certificate), 
    x509_issuerName(c.certificate) FROM certificate c, certificate_identity ci WHERE 
    c.id= ci.certificate_id AND ci.name_type = 'dNSName' AND lower(ci.name_value) = 
    lower(?) AND x509_notAfter(c.certificate) > statement_timestamp()''',(domain_name,))
```

More generically:

```
c.execute('''SELECT columnX FROM tableA where columnY = ? AND columnZ =?'''
    (desired_columnY_value,desired_columnZ_value))
```

Comment: @roganjosh ah i see the `dNSName` now, you are right. But why does `"""` vs `'''` matter? They're the same to python?

Comment: I don't understand your comment roganjosh. ''' is standard for multiline strings in python. I always use it for SQL statements as they are liable to grow! Also, using ? and allowing cursor.execute() to interpolate the values is the documented way to do this. See https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Cursor

Comment: @SuperStew yes, it's a misread on my part. But I think editing it to use `"""` will get the SO formatting correct. I daren't try on my phone.

Comment: @T_Burgis Thanks for your answer! I tried implementing that code and I got the following traceback:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "5:33pm", line 43, in <module>
    connect_to_db()
  File "5:33pm", line 32, in connect_to_db
    lower(?) AND x509_notAfter(c.certificate) > statement_timestamp()''',(domain_name))
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near ")"
LINE 4: lower(?) AND x509_notAfter(c.certificate) > statement_timest...

Comment: @TBurgis I was wrong sorry. It's wonky highlighting in the SO editor.

Comment: @bedford - I think I've messed up the indenting of your statement. The 2nd-4th lines should be indented relative to the cursor.execute line. New to stackoverflow and not completely comfortable with the editor yet.

Comment: I'm going to try an edit from my phone. You also want to pass the parameter as a tuple.

Comment: I've edited the original answer to include proper indentation.

Comment: Hmmm ok, you've gone back and deliberately changed my edit that you left alone at first. Why? Now we're back at what I said was incorrect. I can't test whether it's actually an issue right now but you can _see_ in your own answer that the string has a mix of black and red text now you reverted the change.

Comment: @roganjosh - the quoting and syntax highlighting look fine in jupyter notebook - I assume the stackoverflow highlighting is generic rather than python specific.

Comment: Meh, I'm losing interest in this (i don't mean that in a dismissive way,). I don't have a proper criticism of the answer, it just seemed a bit trivial to revert a change that fixed the formatting here. Anyway, welcome to SO :)

Comment: @roganjosh That seemed to work. Do you have any idea of how to add this "x509_*(c.certificate)" to the SELECT clause. I tried adding it to the end of the SELECT statement after adding a comma but I got this error message: Traceback (most recent call last): File "5:33pm", line 43, in <module> connect_to_db() File "5:33pm", line 32, in connect_to_db lower(%s) AND x509_notAfter(c.certificate) > statement_timestamp()''',(domain_name,)) psycopg2.ProgrammingError: column "x509_" does not exist LINE 2: x509_issuerName(c.certificate), x509_*(c.certificate) FROM c...